# What is difference between overwrite and append to parquet

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

What is the difference between append and overwrite to parquet in spark.
I'm processing huge amount of data for say 10 days. At present I'm processing daily logs into parquet files using "append" method and partitioning the data based on date. But the problem I'm facing is daily data is also very huge and taking a lot of time, contributing to high CPU usage as well while processing data using EMR cluster. This is making my job very slow and expensive. So I'm looking for a way where I can further split the data and can merge the data to day cluster.

Comment: The title and body do not match.

Answer (score 0):

Please see spark SaveMode docs
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/index.html